# why datatables.net-bs4 is not improving table appearance?

Tags: node.js, datatables

I am trying to improve the appearance of an HTML table using `datatables.net-bs4` package. I am loading it as mentioned on the npm website as follows:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require( 'datatables.net-bs4' )( window, $ );
```

Then using it as follows:

```
$('#go_table').DataTable({
    responsive: true
});
```

but the table looks ugly (see screenshot below).
I made sure that jquery (3.5.1) is installed.
I will appreciate any suggestions to fix this error.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that all the css has been loaded in the devtools of your browser??

Comment: will the data tables.net-bs4 package not automatically load required CSS as it contains distribution files required to style? Maybe I misunderstood your comment as I am new to front-end programming, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

is not error but you did't load css style.

~datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css